# Revenue year by year SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query which provides me with the item and item details, values, rate and quantity across each location.

I am trying to get the yearly revenue based on the Start and End Date. Example, if the chosen date was 2013-2015. The final result will create 3 columns one for 2013 revenue, one for 2014 revenue and one for 2015 revenue.

I am a newbie and still not an expert in writing queries, but here is what I have currently:

```
SELECT 
   department,
   item,
   itemdesc,
   qty1,
   qty2,
   rate_1,
   rate_2,
   SUM(mm.days*mm.rate*mm.qty)
FROM 
   items it
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT 
       i.days, i.rate, i.days, ii.todate, ii.itemid
    FROM 
       invoiceofitems ii
    JOIN 
       invoices i on i.id = ii.id
    WHERE 
       ii.todate BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate) mm ON mm.itemid = it.itemid
GROUP BY 
    department,
    item,
    itemdesc,
    qty1, qty2,
    rate_1, rate_2
ORDER BY 
    item
```

However, this does not provide me with a year to year aggregation of invoice revenue that I require.

I know this is possible to achieve via iterating through this. But how would I accomplish this and where would I start on this?

Would I need to know the start and end date of each year and iterate through that and then add a counter to the year until year= EndDate?

I'm extremely confused. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want a column for each year?  Why not a row?

Comment: Well the idea is to know how much revenue the item generated each year based on the start and end date. So I think column would make the most sense? Am I wrong to assume that?

Comment: I think splitting it into rows makes the most sense.  A SQL column is much less dynamic than a row.  You have to use dynamic SQL or generated SQL to get a variant number of columns whereas with a row you can just group them and get what you want

Comment: Okay how would I that via rows then?

Comment: Just do group by year - why are you grouping by department and item, etc?

Comment: Because I am using the SUM function

Answer (score 0):

I hope that PIVOT and YEAR help you to solve this problem (some columns are omitted):

```
;WITH SRC(department,item, ... , rate_2, yr, calculation) AS
(SELECT it.department, it.item, ..., it.rate_2,  YEAR(ii.todate) as yr, 
   (i.days * i.rate *i.qty) as calculation
FROM items it
LEFT JOIN invoiceofitems ii ON ii.itemid = it.itemid
JOIN invoices i ON i.id = ii.id)
SELECT department,item, ..., [2013],[2014],[2015]
FROM SRC
PIVOT
(SUM(calculation) FOR yr IN ([2013],[2014],[2015])) PVT
```

The YEAR function returns only 'year' part of your date and makes grouping easier. PIVOT just rotates grouped data from rows to columns.